# Error connected with Database management system core when i'm installing MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, installation

Error code: **0x84B40002** OS: Windows 10. SQL Server 2022 (16.x)

SQL Server repairing programm says that i have to delete Database management system core.
I already tried to completely delete  SQL Server and all it's components from computer but error message still the same.
Log:

```
Overall summary:
   Final result: Error: see below for more information
   Exit code (Decimal): -2068578302
   Start time: 2024-01-25 19:41:56
   End time: 2024-01-25 19:44:09
   Requested action: Repair

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
   Next step for SQLEngine: Resolve the error using the following information, and then run the installation process again.


Machine Properties:
   Machine name: DESKTOP-6CTHV3U
   Machine processor count: 4
   OS version: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19045)
   OS service pack:
   OS region: Russia
   OS language: Russian (Russia)
   OS architecture: x64
   Process architecture: 64-bit version
   OS clustered: No

Product features discovered:
   Product Instance Instance ID Feature Language Edition Version Clustered Configured
   SQL Server 2022 SQLEXPRESS MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS Database Engine Services 1033 Express Edition 16.0.1000.6 No Yes
   SQL Server 2022 SQLEXPRESS MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS Database Engine Services 1049 Express Edition 16.0.1000.6 No Yes

Package properties:
   Description: Microsoft SQL Server 2022
   ProductName: SQL Server 2022
   Type: RTM
   Version: 16
   SPLevel: 0
   Installation location: C:\SQL2022\Express_RUS\x64\setup\
   Installation edition: Express

Note. Review the Microsoft SQL Server software license terms at aka.ms/useterms.

User input options:
   ACTION: Repair
   AGTDOMAINGROUP: <empty>
   AGTSVCACCOUNT: <empty>
   AGTSVCPASSWORD: <empty>
   AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE: Manual
   ASCONFIGDIR: Config
   ASSVCACCOUNT: <empty>
   ASSVCPASSWORD: <blank>
   ASTELSVCACCT: <blank>
   ASTELSVCPASSWORD: <blank>
   ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE: 0
   CONFIGURATIONFILE:
   ENU: false
   EXTSVCACCOUNT: <empty>
   EXTSVCPASSWORD: <blank>
   FAILOVERCLUSTERGROUP: <blank>
   FAILOVERCLUSTERNETWORKNAME: <empty>
   FTSVCACCOUNT: <empty>
   FTSVCPASSWORD: <empty>
   HELP: false
   IACKNOWLEDGEENTCALLIMITS: false
   INDICATEPROGRESS: false
   INSTANCENAME: SQLEXPRESS
   ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT: NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
   ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD: <blank>
   ISMASTERSVCPORT: 8391
   ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN: <empty>
   ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE: Automatic
   ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT: <blank>
   ISSVCACCOUNT: NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
   ISSVCPASSWORD: <blank>
   ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE: Automatic
   ISTELSVCACCT: <blank>
   ISTELSVCPASSWORD: <blank>
   ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE: 0
   ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT: NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
   ISWORKERSVCCERT: <blank>
   ISWORKERSVCMASTER: <blank>
   ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD: <blank>
   ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE: Automatic
   QUIET: false
   QUIETSIMPLE: false
   SQLSVCACCOUNT: NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
   SQLSVCPASSWORD: <empty>
   SQLTELSVCACCT: NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS
   SQLTELSVCPASSWORD: <blank>
   SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE: Automatic
   SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE: false
   SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
   UIMODE: AutoAdvance

   Configuration file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20240125_194154\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
   Feature: Database Engine Services
   Status: Failure
   Reason for failure: An error occurred while installing the component.
   Next Step: Resolve the error using the following information, and then run the installation process again.
   Component name: SQL Server Database Engine service instances
   Component error code: 0x84B40002
   Error description: The SQL Server component "SQL_Engine_Core_Inst" is in a non-recoverable state because its configuration was not completed successfully. Only successfully installed computers can be restored
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: "The SQL Server component "SQL_Engine_Core_Inst" is in a non-recoverable state because its configuration was not completed successfully. Only successfully installed computers can be restored" - It's telling you that you can't run repair on it because it wasn't successfully installed.

Comment: @SeanGallardy how i said in question i already tried to reinstall Sql Server but it didnt help

Comment: You also show the log which shows a repair and not an install.

Comment: @SeanGallardy i think they have almost same info but i can upload install log if its necessary

Comment: You're stating that when you install a new instance (of which two already show installed which are both express edition) that you get an error that you can't run repair on the instance? Seems suspect. Again, the information given is unhelpful and doesn't match the description. What does the summary log say? What does the detail log say?

Comment: This will be a helpful resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Did you delete regedit folders like HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @mbielsa yes i did